# Extended Display with Two Monitors - How to Watch Full Screen Across BOTH monitors in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, display

When I do full screen of a movie or anything else it just does one screen, how can I do both in Windows 10 ?

Comment: Do you mean duplicated displays or stretched across both screens?

Comment: stretched across both screens when i tell video player to do full screen, not on just one

Comment: Settings-Home-Display lets you make both monitors work like one big one. I don't know if that will help. You can try it.

Comment: Where is that ?  Sorry my windows doesnt have that

Comment: @sheeple See [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4561931/how-to-use-multiple-monitors-in-windows-10) at the end under "Choose a display option". You're probably looking for the "Extend" option.